# Test for surjective and injective give a function

Tags: functions

In my university mathematics course, we are covering functions and their properties, amongst which are injective and surjective properties.

Here is a example from my material which I do not fully understand. What is the link from the last r result (the quadratic equation) containing `4 +/- sqrt(16+4p)` and the  `but then  16 + 4p  >= 0`

This does not make and logical sense, to me atleast!

What is this line's "function" (why am I extracting this out of the equation) in proving/testing for a surjective function

> [image: Function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That whole example aims to prove that the function is (or not) "onto" and "1 on 1".

"onto" means that he wants to test if the range of the function is the real numbers 
(the set given as the image of the definition of the function)

$\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $
$$
r \in Dom[\alpha] \quad p \in Ran[\alpha]
$$
To do that he wants to see if $\alpha(r) = r^2 - 4 r = p$ satisfies $ \forall p \in \mathbb{R}$
and he reaches to $ r = \frac{4\pm\sqrt{16+4p}}{2} $ now, ask if p would be valid for all $\mathbb{R}$ and the result is not, because $\sqrt{16+4p}$ would be a complex number ( $\mathbb{C}$) if $p < -4 $. This will mean that $r \in \mathbb{C}$ but $r \in  Dom[\alpha] $ which is $\mathbb{R}$.

So $p$ can't take all the $\mathbb{R}$ and the function is not "onto".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, no where on our module material does it make mention of this method (not meaning it is invalid), just that we are expected to understand this...somehow...but thanks to you, it makes perfect sense, had to give it a moment to sink in though :p Thank you

Comment: I've been an student, I understand where people struggle :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of the reason why 16+4p is nonnegative:
r is supposed to be a real number. If 16+4p were negative, then we would have a negative number underneath a square root, which gives a complex number rather than a real number. Does that make sense?

In other words, if p is less than 4, then the value [4+- root(16+4p)]/2 is not a real number but rather a complex number. Have your learned about complex numbers?

Comment: I understand you point, but I might have not been as clear as I thought, what I do not understand, what allows me to take a value out of a squareroot and suddenly that becomes a step to an answer. There is no logical connection between the 16+4p within the sqaureroot and the step denoted by the "but then 16+ ..."

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding the wording of the solution written in the textbook, my advice would be to try to prove the problem yourself without looking at the solution. Afterwords, the wording in the textbook might start to make sense. I use this strategy when I don't understand the wording of a particular solution and it consistently works for me :)

Comment: I try/tried that with most to all examples but this one and a previous one caught me...just function things xD

Answer (score 0):

I find the given explanation very misleading.

Let's call the function $f$ (instead of $\propto$), so $f(x)=x^2-4x$.

Start with $y\in\mathbb{R}$; you want to see whether there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$. This reduces to solving the equation
$$
x^2-4x=y
$$
in the unknown $x$. It is a quadratic: $x^2-4x-y=0$, so it has a solution if and only if the discriminant is nonnegative:
$$
16+4y\ge0
$$
that is, $y\ge-4$. The range of the function $f$ is the set of real numbers such that the equation above has a solution, hence the interval $[-4,\infty)$.

This shows the function is not onto.

This also shows the function is not $1$–$1$, because for $y>-4$ the equation above has *two* distinct solutions.

However, we could also check it directly. Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$, which becomes
$$
a^2-4a=b^2-4b
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
a^2-b^2-4a+4b=0
$$
or
$$
(a-b)(a+b)-4(a-b)=0
$$
or
$$
(a-b)(a+b-4)=0
$$
This shows that either $a=b$ or $a+b-4=0$. In particular, if we find $a$ and $b$ such that $a\ne b$ and $a+b-4=0$, we have proved the function is not $1$–$1$. Choose $a=4$ and $b=0$ and the above shows $f(4)=f(0)$.

Comment: hi,, your explanations seems most understandable, but I have a request, since I am still a llittle lost, could you put this explanation in terms of x;y and using f instead of alpha, since range = y or apha(x), but in the given info, r is y (y=r^2-4r) or (f(r) = r^2-4r), if this makes sense. I do not understand if r is y or x.

Comment: Also, if I understand the last part correctly, by a and b exists such that a + b -4 != 0, then f is a 1-1? taking into consideration the previous statement a+b-4.. what happens in the case where a=b and a !=b?what are the results and conclusions I can draw from each of the 'a=' and '!= b'

Comment: @user2699451 No, that's incorrect. The function would be one-to-one only if for all $a$ and $b$, if $a\ne b$ then $a+b-4\ne0$. I changed notation as per your request.